# Jasper HTML output width issue

Tags: jasper-reports

This report is generated with jasper reporting tool with REST API. Report data is showing in an HTML page with an iframe. After loading data to the iframe, report HTML view showing a lot of white spaces in the right and left side. I have tried with increasing the iframe width in CSS. But this is not affecting the report. Is it possible to adjust white spaces from jasper report itself? I am using page size as A4 landscape.

I have attached the image:

[image]

Hi,
I have attached the image once again, You can see the Blank spaces on left and right side. How to remove this?. i have attached the jrxml link also. please help.

[image]
https://files.fm/u/56nnrd9z
Hi,
 I have attached the Jrxml code link once again, please check it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P9aeNW7YTIndNDyv8jkCwO_RQGf32iZu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you looked at the generated HTML/CSS to see what would need to change to make this responsive? Are you able to add any custom CSS to meet that objective?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi,
We can't increase size with CSS. With css we can increase only the size of iframe. But our report data is generated from jasper side. I need to increase report width from Jasper without change the page size . Is it possible in jasper report?

Comment: I don't know Jasper Report (and this question may be too broad without more information). However, if I were doing this, I would set up a web proxy that added custom CSS to add the responsive behaviour you are seeking.

Comment: @barshan: Create a minimal example that shows the problem. Over 570 lines of JRXML is not minimal. Try to show the problem in less than 100 lines, if you can. Remove all code that is not relevant to the problem but still reproduces the issue (i.e., that we can load and run in our own environment).

Answer (score 2):

Various settings affect the output width of HTML reports, including:

- [Size unit](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration.html#setSizeUnit-net.sf.jasperreports.export.type.HtmlSizeUnitEnum-) (POINT vs PIXEL)
- [Zoom ratio](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration.html#setZoomRatio-java.lang.Float-)
- [Page margins](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration.html#setIgnorePageMargins-java.lang.Boolean-)

For example:

```
final SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();

configuration.setIgnorePageMargins(true);
configuration.setSizeUnit(POINT);

// Or try this instead of setSizeUnit(POINT)...
//configuration.setZoomRatio(2.0f);

final HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

If there are images in the report, consider using SVG format to avoid pixelation.
Additional information about these settings is at:

- https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4483
- https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/6577

From the JasperSoft community site, you can set the zoom ratio in a JRXML file, described as follows:

> You should be able to set a default zoom value by setting this property at report level:
>
> `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.viewer.zoom" value="FitWidth" />`
>
> Other possible values:
>
> - ActualSize
> - FitHeight
> - FitPage
> - integers (e.g., 2 for 200%)
> - decimals (e.g., 0.5 for 50%)

Comment: Update your question, @barshan. Create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include Java source code showing how the report is generated, include additional screen shots, and paste the entire JRXML code.

Comment: @barshan: That is insufficient. Please update the question with Java source code, JRXML source code, and ensure you have a minimal working example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Hi Sir, 
we are not using java code, only using the jrxml template file and the report is running through rest api. I have attache the jrxml code one again.